# Getting a variable from PHP to javascript (echo not updating after PHP variables change)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm working on a script that forms a web page based on what is in my database. For his I call a java script function when the page loads and whenever the page needs to update.

Firstly I made a script that gets the information from the database, passes it to java script by `echo "var region_list = ". $js_region_list . ";\n";` and then proceeded to generate the page itself which worked.

After that I tried to get this to work based on an AJAX request but this failed horribly. As it stands I get correct information from the database but it does not change the value of `echo "var region_list = ". $js_region_list . ";\n";` which prevents the page from updating.

The PHP part of my script:

```
if(isset($_POST["campaign_id"])){
// Get variables and sanetize
$campaign_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $campaign_id);

// Create planet list
$planet_list = array();
$sql = "SELECT planet_nr, size, moon FROM planets WHERE campaign_id = $campaign_id";
if ($result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($planet_list, array($row["planet_nr"],$row["size"],$row["moon"]));
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

// Create region list
$region_list = array();
$sql = "SELECT planet_id, region_id, region_type, owner FROM regions WHERE campaign_id = $campaign_id";
if ($result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($region_list, array($row["planet_id"],$row["region_id"],$row["region_type"],$row["owner"]));
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

// Convert array's for use in java
$js_planet_list = json_encode($planet_list);
$js_region_list = json_encode($region_list);

$list = array($planet_list, $region_list);
$list = json_encode($list);
echo $list;
exit();
```

The javascript part:

```
<?php
echo "var planet_list = ". $js_planet_list . ";\n";
echo "var region_list = ". $js_region_list . ";\n";
?>
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "campaign.php?c="+campaign_id);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
        if(ajax.responseText == "Fail"){
            alert(ajax.responseText);
        }
    }
}
ajax.send("campaign_id="+campaign_id);
```

NOTE: These are just snippets of the whole script. The whole script is in the same PHP file with the PHP up above between it's tags and the java down between the script tags.

Comment: Do you have a `<script>` tag?

Comment: the script is inlined in your php file? you can use instead `var planet_list = <?php echo $yourvariable; ?>`

Comment: You have several issues. 1) sql injections 2) trying to generate javascript using PHP. 3) not using templating on your frontend

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen Yes, I'm just showing snippets since the actual file is 300+ lines most of which is not relevant.

Comment: @threeFatCat I've tried that and it gives the same result

Comment: @HBensiali At the moment I'm just trying to get things to work. Once everything is up and running I'm going to get everything checked security wise.

As for generating javascript with PHP these are seperate parts of a page the first part is pure PHP to get the variables from my database and the second part is javascript between the script tags with a little PHP to get the variables there.

I'm not following on you last point, I'm still new with php, html, javascritp, etc

Comment: the other thing, you're passing the variable `campaign_id` in your ajax call but above you're ajax call you have `planet_list` and  `region_list` where is the value of the `campaign_id`?

Comment: @threeFatCat campaign_id is taken from elsewhere.

As the script is now everything works correctly to the point where the PHP script ends. The last bit where I add both $planet_list and $region_list to $list is a little test for myself to see what their values are and they are correct.

But even though their values are correct at php level they don't change down at the java script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax success part, you need to just update the values of the the variables planet_list and region_list as shown below

```
planet_list = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText[0]);
region_list = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText[1]);
```

Comment: I've tried that but when I use alert to see the values of planet_list and region_list I get [ on both so I'm thinking ajax.response is treated as a string instead of an array for some reason.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it ;)

Comment: @Ivaldir glad to help. I have updated my response accordingly.